# Span dimension, vector space dimension, spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If the dimension of the span of a subset $X$ is equal to the dimension of the vector space $V$, is $X$ a spanning set of $V$?

Comment: If the dimensions are finite then yes. The reason is that *any* large enough set of linearly independent vectors form a basis.

Answer (score 2):

In a space $V$ of dimension $n$ the only subspace $X$ of dimension $n$ is $V$ itself. Indeed, if there is a vector $v$ which is not in this subspace then the span of $X\cup \{v\}$ would have dimension greater than the dimension of $V$ which is impossible. Hence $X$ must be equal to $V$.